# Qlik Sense - KPI - columns in expression coming from what table?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a Qlik Sense app using different kind of charts, among them, a KPI with 5 measures. 
The app's data is coming from multiple tables.

The problem I have is that 3 of the measures in the KPI are calculated using Columns(), but I don't know to what columns the expressions are referring to.

For example:

1. Percent: `=Column(1)/Column(2)-1`
2. Arrow Up: `=IF(Column(3)>0,'▲',null())`
3. Arrow Down: `=IF(Column(3)<0,'▼',null())`

So, the app's data is coming from multiple tables, there is no table chart in the app. How can I determine to what "column" the expressions is referring to?
[image: Columns() use]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column() function refers to the expressions in the object you are working with not to the underlying data. So that looks like column 1 is Sales for this year and column 2 is Sales for last year